# Way to look at AWS cloudfront logs in near real-time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have configured to send Cloudfront logs to a S3 bucket. However, the logs files in the S3 bucket show up as .gz files one after another.

My objective is to send traffic to this web site and troubleshoot issues in real-time or near-real-time.

Having to download and gunzip files and then searching through them does not provide a good solution.

Does anyone have a better way to look at **cloudfront logs in real-time or near-realtime**?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean access logs? They are not real time, and can be delayed up to [24h even](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html). Better to look at CloudWatch metrics for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CloudFront's real-time logs feature to send your logs to a Kinesis Data Stream.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/real-time-logs.html